# Limit results from a MYSQL query based on partial string value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have content in a field that is identified with `|costume` and `|party`.

Is it possible to limit the results to ONLY those data sets containing one or the other of the identifiers?

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM ezpages_content WHERE LIKE "|party" NOT IN pages_title
```

but that just gives a syntax error. The desired results from that would have been to return all data that was `|costume`.

I'm not even sure if you can check part of an entry in a field.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your requirement, but you may looking for `NOT LIKE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM ezpages_content WHERE pages_title NOT LIKE "%|party%"
```

Comment: Thanks @JaydipJ. That did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not even sure if you can check part of an entry in a field.

You can using the `%` wildcard operator combined with `LIKE` or `NOT LIKE`.

Here's two examples of the correct syntax for you. Which one you use depends on your expected results:

Syntax #1: `SELECT * FROM ezpages_content WHERE pages_title LIKE "%|costume%"`

Syntax #2: `SELECT * FROM ezpages_content WHERE pages_title NOT LIKE "%|party%"`.

The first query will return any results where `|costume` is in the pages title, regardless of whether or not `|party` or some other identifier is present. The second query will return any results where pages title does not include `|party`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `NOT LIKE` operator in MySQL. It is used to used to **exclude** those rows which are matching the criterion followed by LIKE operator.

So your query might look something like this (To exclude rows containing **|party** text in it),

```
SELECT * FROM ezpages_content WHERE pages_title NOT LIKE "%|party%"
```

To exclude rows containing **|costume** text in it, query would look something like this,

```
SELECT * FROM ezpages_content WHERE pages_title NOT LIKE "%|costume%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a case usage there are countless ways to do this. The easiest and likely best performing would simply be

```
WHERE pages_title <> '|party'
```